# Having issue with Xcode 6 install

Tags: xcode6

I downloaded Xcode 6 but got an icon with a Stop sign.  After copying it to Applications, it remains the same and won't react to click.  Any idea what I am missing? I am running OSX 10.9.3.

[image]

Comment: I assume you have dont have Yosemite. I realized that you need to have OSX Yosemite to work with xcode 6

Comment: @DavidG. No, you do not need Yosemite. I'm run Xcode 6 GM on Mavericks  (10.9.4) just fine.

Comment: @Maddy I know that you should be able to run Xcode 6 GM on both Mavericks and Yosemite. But as I tried to install it on my MacBook Air with Mavericks I were prompted that I am not able to run Xcode 6 GM on this OSX Version, that I would need to have Yosemite. I then tried it on my iMac with Yosemite and it worked fine. So I assumed that you need to have Yosemite to run it.

Comment: According to the doc, you only need 10.9.3 and up.

Comment: I upgraded to 10.9.4 and it works.  Looks like there is a mistake in the documentation.